# url_for Rails 3 versus Rails 2 changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have migrated a Rails 2 application to Rails 3. But now I'm encountering the following issue.  In one of my view files I am calling the following javascript (with JQuery):

```
$.getJSON("<%= url_for(:controller => :visit_types, :action => :get_color)%>" + '/' + calEvent.visit_type_id, function(data) { calEvent.color = data;});
```

when it loads the page, I get the error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"visit_types", :action=>"get_color"}

`rake routes` outputs:

```
/visit_types/get_color/:id(.:format)    {:controller=>"visit_types",:action=>"get_color"}
```

It is true. I don't pass the `:id` in the `url_for()` call. But it in Rails 2 this was possible. How can I solve this?

Comment: Not much of a choice here: either pass an id or add a route that doesn't require the id.

Answer (score 0):

I see you add the id manually in javascript. 
You should write:

```
<%= url_for(:controller => :visit_types, :action => :get_color, :id => calEvent.visit_type_id)%>
```

If you run `rake routes` you would normally also see a string in front, and this string is the name you could use instead of the generic `url_for` (just append `_url` or `_path`), in your case this will be something like

```
get_color_visit_types_url(calEvent.visit_type_id)
```

I find this form to be more expressive. Also note that you could give a better or more specific name in your routes-file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. but I am still struggling
Your proposal doesn't help me because the calEvent.visit_type_id is a javascript variable.
So when I render the .html.erb view file, I get the error:

undefined local variable or method `calEvent' for

I added the following entry to my rails3 routes.rb:

match 'visit_types/get_color' => 'visit_types#get_color'
And now I can make it work with the 
"<%= url_for(:controller => :visit_types, :action => :get_color)%>"  + '/' + calEvent.visit_type_id
construction.
Still, I don't like the solution.
I there a nicer solution to solve this issue ?